# Hidden services using manually configured browser

Tags: onion-services, configuration

I've been playing around with regular Tor, compiled from source (as opposed to TBB).
I've found that while accessing regular websites works fine hidden services don't work at all.
For instance, accessing the [duckduckgo hidden service](https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/) yields:

> Server not found: Firefox can't find the server at 3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion.

I have Firefox configured to use the SOCKSv5 proxy localhost:9050.

When I access [Are you using Tor?](https://check.torproject.org/) it says "Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Firefox to use your SOCKS proxy also for hostname resolution.

Set `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` to `true`. (In about:config)