# Browser configured but still unable to unblock websites

Tags: configuration, firefox, socks

I have downloaded and installed Tor. Now, I wanted to use Tor to visit some of the blocked websites that our government had mistakenly blocked. So, I changed the proxy settings in my Firefox to point at localhost:9150.

Now, when I check my IP address, it is masked, but I'm still not able to visit the blocked website.

If I use the Tor Browser Bundle, however, I am able to visit the site.

So what is the difference in the settings in my Firefox and the Tor Browser??

PS: The blocked website I am trying to visit is github!! Yes, it was banned in India recently but soon the ban was lifted. My ISP is lazy though. They are still blocking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your ISP has just removed that site from their DNS.

To test this, see if you can access .onion sites with your Firefox? If you can with Tor Browser but not with your Firefox, then this is most likely it.

If so, you should set your browser to use the SOCKS proxy for hostname resolution as well:
Set `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` to `true`. (In about:config)
(Same issue as this: [Hidden services using manually configured browser](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/hidden-services-using-manually-configured-browser) )

Comment: Okay. Yep. That solved it.